# Wordpress Plugin - Membership With Upload Functionality

Tags: wordpress, membership

I have had a look around but cannot currently find a plugin that combines membership / upload functionality.

What I envisage happening is a logged in member uploads documents and has these documents displayed on their profile, along with the ability to manage them, so add new docs and delete docs.

I like the wp-members plugin for the membership functionality but need this additional upload facility that will display the docs on the profile for that user and will then allow an admin to download them.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

wp-members is very good plugin for membership functionality,

However you can always do little bit customization with you own custom field.

Check this tutorial [Adding Custom Fields in WP-Members](http://butlerblog.com/2010/09/27/adding-custom-fields-in-wp-members/) for your own custom fields.

Hope, This will help you!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but this does not cater for the functionality that I need.